# php imagecopyresampled is not changing image, but no errors?

Tags: php, image-processing

the image.jpg is 400 x 400. I want the image to be 200x 200 instead of 400x400 and optimize it at 75%.  The code below has no errors, nothing on console, error log, etc. BUT the image does not change?

```
  $source = "/path/to/image.jpg";
  $srcImg = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
  $destImg = imagecreatetruecolor( 200,200 );
  imagecopyresampled( $destImg, $srcImg, 0, 0, 0,0, 200,200, 400, 400);
  imagejpeg($destImg, $srcImg, 75);
```

Do you see the problem?

EDIT:  imagejpeg is failing at the moment, but imagecopyresampled returns true?

SOLVED:  imagejpeg working with using source variable

```
  $source = "/path/to/image.jpg";
  $srcImg = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
  $destImg = imagecreatetruecolor( 200,200 );
  imagecopyresampled( $destImg, $srcImg, 0, 0, 0,0, 200,200, 400, 400);
  imagejpeg($destImg, $source, 75);
```

AND it now works for resizing as well?

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that there are no errors being generated?

Comment: I got errors before with the font setting, but that value doesn't give error now?

Comment: You edited your question into one that's guaranteed to get closed (a request for best way / recommendation). I've reverted it.

Comment: What about permissions?

Comment: What value is ``imagepng()`` returning?

Comment: kmoser, your correct, that imagejpeg (was using png) is failing??